# HighCharts Plotlines with Multiple Y-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I have been able to generate a HighCharts chart with multiple y-axis like this [chart with multiple y-axis](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) and I have been able to generate a chart with a single y-axis and plot line like this [chart with plot lines and single y-axis](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines).  Is it possible to combine the two so that I can have multiple y-axis and at least one plot line?  I am not exactly sure where to start.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you try just adding the plot line code to your multiple y axis chart? that's all you need to do :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is. You should simply combine the code of each chart options. Include **`plotLines`** in the axis you want the plotLines on:

```
{ // Secondary yAxis
        plotLines: [{
            value: 50,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'shortdash',
            width: 2,
            zIndex: 10,
            label: {
                text: 'Minimum'
            }
        }, {
            value: 150,
            color: 'red',
            dashStyle: 'shortdash',
            width: 2,
            zIndex: 10,
            label: {
                text: 'Maximum'
            }
        }],

        ...
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqz1zuuo/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Raeen Hashemi!  This answered my question perfectly!  I almost had it last night but bleary eyes could not parse all of the commas, parentheses, brackets, and semicolons. :)